# hide jquery tabs and its content until page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, onload

I want to hide jquery tabs until my page loads completely.

I tried adding a display:none at the tabs div

```
<div class="tabscontent" style"display:none;">
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href=\"#tabs-1\">...</a></li>
        <li><a href=\"#tabs-2\">...</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id=\"tabs-1\">...../div>   
    <div id=\"tabs-2\">....</div>

</div>
</div>
```

and at the end of my page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).onload( function(){
        jQuery('.tabscontent').fadeIn(1000);

    });
    } );
</script>
```

When my page loads the tabscontent div is still hidden

The tabscontent class is the div containing all tabs code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="tabscontent" style="display:none;">
```

and the jquery would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
        jQuery('.tabscontent').fadeIn(1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry i just edited my post I have the correct style applied already

Comment: You still left out the = sign in style="display: none;"

Comment: onload is a javascript function what you want is the jQuery function $(document).ready(function(){ or you can use the shortcut $(function(){